# Do serotonin drugs contain serotonin or a precursor to it, e.g. tryptophan?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, drugs

With serotonin drugs, is it actually serotonin in the drug, or is it tryptophan which converts into serotonin through the biochemical conversion process after the drug is consumed? Serotonin can be consumed through foods, whereas tryptophan cannot, but the biochemical conversion process is what has brought this question to my mind about the actual drugs which can increase serotonin in the body.

Comment: I think you've got largely (if not exclusively) misconceptions here.  It might be best to do some basic research on something like Wikipedia and then ask a follow-up question to that.

Answer (score 1):

No, the drugs that interact with serotonin receptors do not contain serotonin nor are they serotonin precursors. There are a lot of serotonin receptor subtypes in the body and the drugs are designed to interact selectively at a single subtype (with greater or lesser success). Many of them bear only a passing resemblance to serotonin as extra functionality is added to enhance selectivity.